# Node.js Discord Bot: Typeerror: Cannot read property of 'send' undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

EDIT: big shout out to the guys who are helping with feedback, still very new to the scene, but just so fascinated by it so i keep trying.
i have enabled a new command handler and it seemed to have just jacked up everything i have. its kind of a general problem throughout my code but if i can get help with this command i will be able to fix it all.

i am currently having a problem with my delete command. it works, but it throws errors and im missing something obvious. any help is greatly appreciated. i seem to have a problem with not defining what i want it to do, it used to work flawlessly when i had a basic command haandler, but i have since moved on to a cleaner one and i know i'm just missing something obvious. damn near wrecked the entire code trying to figure it out

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\commands\delete.js:9:56)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\events\guild\message.js:17:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

main.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] });
const fs = require('fs');


client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

COMMAND HANDLER

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('js'))

    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

*I THINK THIS IS MY EXECUTE COMMAND. also known as my message.js*

```
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    const send = require ('discord.js');

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || 
        client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);  

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord);
    } catch (err) {
        message.reply("whoops, shit got fuckity on my backend");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

DELETE COMMAND

```
const message = require("../events/guild/message");
module.exports = {
    name: 'delete',
    description: "delete messages",
        execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
            try {
            if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("type a number with the command doofus");
            if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("bruh enter a real number");

            if (args[0] > 100) return message.channel.send("way too much");
            if (args[0] < 1) return message.channel.send("stop tryna be a funny guy")

            return message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] }).then(messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);


                message.channel.send("you saw nothing");
            })
     } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error returned? What's the code that throws the error?

Comment: added it to original post, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Your `async execute(client, message, args, Discord)` should be non-async, with `return message.channel.messages.fetch(...)` instead of `await message.channel.messages.fetch(...)`.

Comment: The error says *"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"* on line 6 in your "delete" command. So obviously `message.channel` is undefined, which would mean that `message` probably is not what you think it is.

Comment: ...and the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` comes from the missing `try/catch` in your delete command. In order to at least keep the bot from crashing, wrap the function body in a `try/catch` block and dump any errors to console.

Comment: We'll need to see what you pass to your `execute` method

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak for the abundance of help. I will look into remedying that.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros you asking me that question and me not even knowing what to show you shows me that i think i might be out of my depth here.  actually, i think i know what you are asking for, i will include it in original post.

Comment: i have added the try/catch, it has gotten rid of the unhandled promise. but know it has given me TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

at Object.execute (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\commands\delete.js:9:56)

at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\discord bot\events\guild\message.js:17:17)

Comment: As I said, the try/catch only prevents the crash. You still have to fix the underlying problem, which is that `message.channel` is not defined, because you're not calling the function the way it is intended. Look at the place that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're execute functions is `execute(client, message, args, Discord)`. So, the first parameter should always be `client`.

However, in your "message.js" file, you wrote:

```
try {
        command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord);
} catch (err) {
        **some code here**
}
```

Here, you're passing in `message` first, so your order of the parameters is messed up. Fix that by rearranging the parameters and the code should work.